#VALUE error on formula based on web query table results via VLOOKUP
I am getting #VALUE for my Cur Portfolio Value which is just multiplying the results of SUMIF (Shares) and VLOOKUP to a web queried table (Cur Market Value), literally just D13*E13 (Cur Portfolio Value). All cells and ranges have been formatted to accounting, number, general with the same error result. I know the web queried table is the issue b/c when I tried the Shares by the number typed in for Cur Market Value, it worked, but I need it to be able to be refreshed.
Image is headers and first 10 rows of my table


If you change the formatting of the cells to General do they change their format or stay the same?  My guess is that the numbers are stored as text and there are some non printable characters (spaces, line breaks) in the cells that cause an issue.

Also just to make sure . is your decimal separator and not ,?

Yes, I've made all the cells General/Number/Accounting (including the linked table) with the same error result. I confirmed the decimal separator is the period and thousands is the comma.

The question was not "if you change the formatting does the formula work?" the Question was "If you change the formatting of the cells to General do they change their format or stay the same?"  Did the format of the numbers change when you changed the format?  I am trying to get a handle on the data as that is the problem not the formula.

My apologies. The Cur Market Value does not change format when the format is changed, the Shares data and the linked table data both do. The formula for Cur Market Value is a simple VLOOKUP: =VLOOKUP(B13,tblMSNLink,3,).

Then the value being brought in is text that looks like numbers and has other characters that is keeping it from being able to turn into a number. You will need to look at the table from where the data is coming to find those characters to deal with them so Excel can convert the text to a true number.  Formatting does not change the underlying value and if it is text it does not magically turn it into a number.

Is it possible to use the NUMBERVALUE function to translate first?
